# Running UWP applications from the command line with "arguments"

Tags: windows, command-line, uwp

## Background

I can run this UWP application by running the following:

```
test://argument=123?other=true
```

This would run the UWP application that is linked to the `test://` protocol and the application would automatically take that `argument=123?other=true`, parse it and perform the actions specified by those parameters.

## Desired outcome

However, I would like to run the application without using any protocol and directly via the executable.

## What I've tried

So far, I've came up with the following:

```
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PackageId\Windows10Universal.exe" -ServerName:ActivatableClassId
```

This does not pass in the parameters so it doesn't automatically perform what I would like it to. I have tried the following but it does not work either:

```
"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PackageId\Windows10Universal.exe" -ServerName:ActivatableClassId "argument=123?other=true"
```

I've also tried to investigate by using Process Monitor and Process Explorer to see what Windows is doing behind the scenes but I can't seem to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling a UWP/Modern app with arguments is discussed in the article
[How to Open a Windows Modern UWP App From the Command Line](https://poetengineer.postach.io/post/how-to-open-windows-modern-app-from-the-command-line).

You need three items of information about the app :

- **Package Name**
  This is the name of the folder where the app is located
  (not the full path), for example:

  ```
  C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_16005.12827.20560.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
  ```
- **Publisher ID**
  This is the weird string at the end of the path, for example
  `8wekyb3d8bbwe`
- **Application ID**
  In the above folder, open the file `AppxManifest.xml`
  and find the executable name in an XML element that looks like this:

  ```
  <Application Id="microsoft.windowslive.calendar" Executable="HxCalendarAppImm.exe" EntryPoint="Executable">
  ```

To call the app you need to compose the string

```
shell:AppsFolder\<Package Name>_<Publisher ID>!<App ID>
```

To pass parameters to the executable, use the Windows `start` command.

For example, to launch Windows Terminal from the command line and
open a specific profile, use:

```
start "" shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App new-tab -p "GitBash"
```

Note that the above command-line won't work without the `start` command.

Comment: I'm trying to pass "protocol" arguments which are different. I've tried to apply your logic and while the application launches, it does not acknowledge the arguments. Note that `test://argument=123?other=true` provides the desired outcome. Here's what I have tried: `start "" shell:AppsFolder\PackageName_PublisherId!App "argument=123"`

Comment: Try `start "" shell:AppsFolder\PackageName_PublisherId!App 123`.

Comment: Note that this requires that the app be programmed to examine its arguments.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. It seems like it must be done through the protocol.

Comment: This app is then not looking at the command-line arguments, only looking at the URL. There is no solution, except if you can modify it to accept arguments.